# How to get a parent's specific next and previous sibling's child in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

This is the markup:

```
<h2>
   <a href="link1.html">text One for link One</a>
</h2>
<p> More text related to link one</p>
<h2>
   <a href="link2.html">text Two for link Two</a>
</h2>
<p> More text related to link two</p>
<h2>
   <a href="link3.html">text Three for link Three</a>
</h2>
<p> More text related to link three</p>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
var prevLink = $(this).closest('h2').prev('h2').find('a').attr('href');
var nextLink = $(this).closest('h2').next('h2').find('a').attr('href');
```

`.this` is the initial link. My understanding is that, `.closest` will take me to parent `h2` tag and from there I an get to next and preveious `h2` tags. `.find` should get me to link and finally `.attr(href)` will get me the attribute.

Now, previous and next element may not exist. Why am I unable to get the correct links? All I get is `undefined`. As an example, If I am on `link2.html`, I want `prevLink` to be `link1.html` and `nextLink` to be `link3.html`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.next()`/`.prev()` methods only select the immediately following or preceding elements, which means that it won't select anything if the `h2` elements have a sibling `p` element in between.

You could use the `.nextAll()`/`.prevAll()` methods instead. Then chain the `.first()` method in order to get the first element in the collection:

```
var prevLink = $(this).closest('h2').prevAll('h2').first().find('a').attr('href');
var nextLink = $(this).closest('h2').nextAll('h2').first().find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: But the website says that `.next` will `Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.` Is `h2` not the right immediate next sibling with a specific selector?

Comment: I get it now. Please correct me if I am wrong. `.next` and `.previous` don't keep looking for a next specific sibling unless it is a match but only look for  just the immediate element.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh Correct. Those methods only select the immediately following or preceding element. If it isn't a `h2` element, nothing is selected. The method doesn't keep looking for a next `h2` element. That's why you would use `.nextAll()` or `.prevAll()` instead. Those methods will select *all* the following or preceding `h2` elements, and `.first()` will select the first one.